# Filtering array values using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to pyspark and need the solution for below question.

In an array [[-1,1,2,4,5],[3,5,6,-6]],  remove the elements which are <=0 and get a square of positive non-zero numbers.

Comment: spark version ??

Comment: spark version 3 and usng python 3

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform` & `filter` higher order functions.

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- ids: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = false)
```

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("new_ids",F.expr("transform(ids,o -> filter(o, i  -> i > 0))")).show()
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|ids                              |new_ids                  |
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
|[[-1, 1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 5, 6, -6]]|[[1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 5, 6]]|
+---------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: any other simple solution using rdd map and filters ?

Comment: this is very simple solution